# UNABLE TO VERIFY LEAF SIGNASTURE, react native with VPN

Tags: react-native, ssl, axios, expo

Trying to connect RN app to vpn,
basically user enters domain, then username and password and the app will use the inputed domain for requests,
only issue, some users have vpn and upon trying it out there i get the error "unable to verify leaf signature", SSL cert is valid when trying with browser

So far I tried with 'https' node lib which ofc doesn't work, I tried reolsving that issue with RN-nodify, but... I'm running expo project so that doesn't work

And the last thing i tried is

```
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
```

Note: I'm using axios for all requests